# Using Firebase user UID with vuefire manual binding

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuefire

In a simple SPA with Vue and Firebase, there are two routes: Login and Chat.

Upon login, the user is redirected to the Chat route where Firebase database bindings are done manually using vuefire's `$bindAsArray()`, inside the `created()` life-cycle hook. This is because the bindings require the `uid` assigned by the Firebase authentication to be available.

This works fine, until the user refreshes the page. If `auth().currentUser` is used to get the `uid`, it returns null. If the `auth().onAuthStateChanged()` watcher is used, Vue attempts to render the component before the Firebase database bindings are done. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I come across this scenario, as workaround I use component wrapper that has `UID` as property, if `UID` is null show a waiting message/animation else show your original component.

My real scenario is a little more complex to post it here (firebase, routing, vuex) but basically that wrapper component should look similar to this

```
<template>
<component :is="CurrentComponent" />
</template>

<script>
import App from './App';
import WaitingAnimation from './WaitingAnimation';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Uid: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    CurrentComponent() {
      return this.Uid == null ? WaitingAnimation : App;
    }
  }
  beforeMount() {
    //While Firebase is initializing `Firebase.auth().currentUser` will be null
    let currentUser = Firebase.auth().currentUser;

    //Check currentUser in case you previously initialize Firebase somewhere else
    if (currentUser) {
      //if currentUser is ready we just finish here
      this.Uid = currentUser.uid;
    } else {
      // if currentUser isn't ready we need to listen for changes
      // onAuthStateChanged takes a functions as callback and also return a function
      // to stop listening for changes 
      let authListenerUnsuscribe = Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        //onAuthStateChanged can pass null when logout 
        if (user) {
          this.Uid = user.uid;
          authListenerUnsuscribe(); //Stop listening for changes
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the idea, but can you please explain the final else block?

Comment: I've added some comments on code, please let me know if you need further explanation

Comment: I didn't know about the return value of onAuthStateChanged(). Everything clear, thank you!